# What are the drawbacks to using callbacks for synchronization of jQuery + CSS animation timing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

CodePen here : http://codepen.io/leifparker/pen/ogboag

I like to use CSS transitions whenever possible, but occasionally hit times where I want javascript code to run after a CSS animation has completed.

I have experimented with `webkitTransitionEnd`, but found it to be a bit flaky (as far as cross-browser reliability).

Setting a javascript timer, `setInterval()`, seems to be the age-old recommended method, but are there any concerns with utilizing an empty (ineffectual) jQuery `.animation()` callback?

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    keepIndent = parseInt($('.kicker').css('text-indent'));
    $('.kicker').toggleClass('active').animate({ 
        textIndent : keepIndent
    },300,function(){
        $('.pebble').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

I toggle the active class on `.kicker`, which animates it with CSS, and then on an (ineffective) `.animate()` callback, I toggle the class on `.pebble`. Obviously, the `.animate(speed)` must match the CSS-transition animation length, for a synchronized delay.

The `keepIndent` variable is used to make the animation visually ineffective, but could be skipped if a property that was not visibly used was assigned an arbitrary value (such as `backgroundPositionX` on an element without a background assigned).

This method seems valid, but I am concerned that there are cross-browser, or sequencing, pitfalls that are not immediately apparent.

Can you think of any reasons not to utilize this method?